# Read plist into nsmutabledictionary, update the dictionary and then save it again

Tags: xcode, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I am really new to saving files in objective C but what I'm trying to accomplish is reading a plist file located in the documents directory on launch or creating it if it doesn't exist.

It should be read in to a NSMutableDictionary. Later on in the app I should be able to save items to the NSMutableDict with categories as keys + text.

The before launch in the viewWillUnload the NSMutableDictionary should be saved into the plist file again.

I have created the plist but I need a way to write to the NSMutableDictionary the right way (category and my result.text string.

And I also need to save the NSMutableDictionary to the plist file and read the plist into the dictionary on launch.

Some help with this would be awsome :D

Thanks guys.

In the savefile void I am doing this:

```
    storeDict = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                 init];
    [storeDict setObject:resultText.text forKey:@"kvitto"];
    [storeDict setObject:kategori forKey:@"kategori"];
    [storeDict writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

saveFilePath looks like this:

```
- (NSString *) saveFilePath {
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"savefile.plist"];
}
```

The values are strings collected from a code that the user have scanned so don't worry bout them.
Well so how do I save this correctly keeping the data that already exists in the savefile.plist.

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you use  writeToFile api? Before writing question here you must google or check apple documentation for NSMutableDictionary.

```
[dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

To load saved dictionary

```
 dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah the questions itself was bad, the real problem was how to add items to the Dictionary itself. When I add items in the viewDidLoad to the dictionary like this (if the list doesn't exist) [dict setValue:@"pizza" forKey:@"food"]; and then when the user presses the save button I try doing the same but with the current value and category selected. When I then nslog the dictionary I only see the values added in the saveTap void and not the ones in viewDidLoad, that's the real q :)

Comment: Oh you're so right here we go updating above post with the code:

Comment: If the dictionary itself contains other dictionaries or arrays, then those will *not* be mutable. Use `NSPropertyListSerialization`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want dictionaries and arrays contained in the dictionary to be mutable as well then do the following:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSError *error;
storeDict = 
    [NSPropertyListSerialization 
            propertyListWithData:data 
                         options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                          format:nil
                           error: &error];
```